# Wid = Widow or Wid = With

Tags: meaning

In the 1800s the abbreviation "wid" is used in city directories.
The first speculation is with a female listed first at an address, the term is used to designate a Widow with the male name following.

For example: Scott, Matilda wid Robert = Widowed?

One contemporary site lists wid = with. Hence Scott, Matilda with Robert.

Which is it?

Comment: *Contemporary* means "from the same time" and refers to the time of the source material, the 1800s city directories, so *modern* would be a better word.

Answer (score 7):

*Wid = widow/widower* (ref: dictionary.com) is the sense used in your city directory

*Wid = with* is used as a slang in chat, sms, etc

Comment: Wid= with originated as an internet slang.

Comment: @zpletan: thanks for the edit, looks complete now. ;)    'wid', 'wth', 'wit' are used as slangs for 'with'.

Comment: wth wouldn't work, it looks like "what the heck"

Comment: *Wid Robert* = Widow **of** Robert (since no-one's mentioned that so far)

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Is "wid" for "with" really Internet slang?  I always thought it was regional American dialect and much older.  For example, in Philadelphia one can order a "[cheesesteak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheesesteak) wid", meaning "with onions".  It's pronounced and often spelled like that, and my impression is this is by no means recent.

Answer (score 0):

Wid means a widow or a widower. Wid (internet slang) also means "with".

Internet slang like "wid" or "dat" or "g8" are short for normal words.

Comment: They are "slang" or "slang words", not "slangs".

Comment: Slang words are considered words too.

Answer (score -1):

WID can also mean "divorced" .... shows up in City Directories and Censuses.  So don't assume that the spouse is dead.  My great-grandmother was "WID" and her divorced husband died after her.